# Internet Explorer not allowing me to call .pauseVideo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube

I'm hoping someone can help me with why my script isn't working in IE 11. Everything works in both Chrome and Firefox and partly works in IE. The problem is that IE doesn't seem to like when I call the function '.pauseVideo()'

IE Console:

> Object doesn't support this property or method 'pauseVideo'

I don't know if this is just some syntax error, or if I need to do something different to support the script in IE 11.

Page displaying error - http://goforward.harpercollege.edu/dev-foundation/index-3.php

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    for (item in players_list) {
      players[players_list[item]] = new YT.Player(players_list[item], {});
    }
  }
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var players = new Array();
  var players_list = [
    "popup-youtube-player-1",
    "popup-youtube-player-2",
    "popup-youtube-player-3",
    "popup-youtube-player-4",
    "popup-youtube-player-5",
    "popup-youtube-player-6"
  ];

  function pauseVideo() {
    for (item in players_list) {
      players[players_list[item]].pauseVideo();
    }
  }

  function swapvid(id) {
    pauseVideo();
    $('.video-slider').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + id).closest('.video-slider').css('display', 'inline');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to be a common issue -  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494996/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-in-ie-8-executes-fine-in-debug) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595658/youtube-js-api-internet-explorer8-inc-10-script438-object-doesnt-suppor). Looks like it's probably because your video slider hides the videos, and IE+YT API doesn't play well with that.

Comment: I commented out all the (display:none) and am still getting the same console error